# Cambiar hover por otra pseudoclase al dar click?

Tags: javascript, css

**Estoy haciendo un memorama, en la cual tengo ahorita mis cartas se encuentran con  hover, para que al pasar el cursor se volten a 180 grados, pero quiero que en lugar de pasar el cursor, al dar click en la carta se cambie de la parte de atras hacia adelante, y asi que pueda ver lo que hay en la carta.**

Este es mi codigo de JavaScript, estoy trayendo las imagenes desde un JSON. dinamicamente

```
//  Traer la data del JSON en un fetch
fetch("../data/memory.json")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data)  => iterarcartas(data))
.catch((error) => console.log(error))


//estante de libros
let carteria = document.getElementById("estante")

//Ierar JSON libros
let iterarcartas = (data) => {
    console.log(data.cartas)
    for (const carta of data.cartas) {
        
      carteria.innerHTML += `<div class="carta-tablero">
                <div class="memorama">
                    <div class="memorama-cover" id='${carta.Nombre}'></div>
                    <div class="memorama-back"><img class="imagen" src='${carta.img}'></div>                  
                </div>
            </div>`
    }
      
}
```

Comment: puedes hacerlo con JS

Comment: ¿sabes como puedo hacerlo desde JavaScript?

Comment: sí, pero sin saber cual es tu código es imposible hacerlo

Comment: Agrega tu CSS en la cual hace `:hover` para poder tener una idea. ¿Y a qué div se hace `:hover`?

Answer (score 0):

Sin código es un poco complicado ayudarte, pero imagino que las cartas son elementos agrupados dentro de otro. De ser así, solo necesitas [registrar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) el evento [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) en el elemento que agrupa a las cartas, y en la función que se ejecutará, verifica si [el elemento clickeado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) es una de las cartas, para lo cual puedes identificarlas con una [clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class). Finalmente, solo te queda [asignar a la carta](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp) la propiedad CSS `transform: rotateY()` para que así pueda girar.